# What is more precise: using an op-amp or internal PGA of an ADC to amplify a low-voltage signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, current-measurement, precision, programmable-gain-amplifier

I'm wanting to current sense a 10A load with high precision. I'm planning to use a current shunt resistor and then amplify/filter this signal before sending it to an ADC. Which design flow is typically more precise?

1. Using a high precision differential op-amp (amplify + level shift) -> buffer -> RC filter -> ADC
2. Using an RC filter -> internal PGA of an ADC to amplify the signal, for example, the ADS131M02IPWT, [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads131m02.pdf)

The intuitive answer is #1, but then I'm wondering why most ADCs have a PGA stage, because it's good enough for the typical application?

Comment: What does "high precision" mean to you??

Comment: I'm trying to achieve <1% error for an energy measurement.

Comment: Is the current sense resistor referred to ground, the same ground as the ADC? If not, what is its voltage with respect ground?

Comment: My application is AC and I'm putting the sense resistor on Neutral.

Comment: You can easily get <1% with either approach.  #1 requires more parts, #2 gives you less flexibility on the input signal.  Whichever you choose be careful if you are planning on building these for any length of time; specialized, single-source parts like the one you mentioned can have a tendency to become hard to get.  I would use a popular ADC with a big user base as a basis for your decision.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to achieve <1% error

Then you should use a Hall Effect sensor instead:

- isolated
- 1 % accurate
- Outputs 0 to 5 V, same as the input range of your ADC.

Comment: I'm considering cost so I have to go with a shunt resistor - I'd rather spend more on a better op-amp/ADC than going with other sensing techniques.